# Azure SQL connection check

Tags: sql, azure

I want to build a database connection test for my CircleCI pipeline, this database is located on Azure and I've found out that pinging this server won't work.

How can I build a test in my CircleCI that determines the integrity of my database connection (basically to see if database is reachable or not). 
Here is a piece of config.yml file:

```
pipeline_test:
   machine: true
   steps:

      - run:
      name: test_Azu_DB_conn
      command: |
          ping zee.database.windows.net
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The service is not reachable by ping.  If you have access to telnet you can use `telnet zee.database.windows.net 1433` to test conectivity.
2. Usually the problem you see is related to **firewalls**.  If you have a firewall then make sure you have outgoing port 1433 enabled.  If your networks require the use of proxy servers then you need to make sure your system is configured to go through the proxy server to access the service.
3. Verify Azure Firewall Settings and Service Availability

[image]
[image]

You can also refer to this [Windows Azure SQL Database Connectivity Troubleshooting Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1719.windows-azure-sql-database-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide.aspx).

There is a [quick troubleshooting guide for Azure SQL Database Connectivity issue.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database)